# PowerShell script to list all user of a group and output group name as well

Tags: powershell-2.0

Is there a script that can list all users of a given group recursively so it covers all nested groups and also lists the name of group (nested child group) that user is part of so i know the group that user is part of

Comment: You need a recursive function for this, I did this a while ago you can take a look and see if that works for you. https://github.com/santysq/Get-Hierarchy

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, Is there anything that can print in a csv format like
group name, user name
parent-group1,user-1
parent-group1,user-2
child-group1,user3
child-child-group1,user4
child-child-group2,user5 
and so on...